# Addressing memory data in 32 bit protected mode with nasm

Tags: memory, nasm

So my book says i can define a table of words like so:

table: dw "13,37,99,99"

and that i can snatch values from the table by incrementing the index into the address of the table like so:

mov ax, [table+2] ; should give me 37

but instead it places 0x2c33 in ax rather than 0x3337

is this because of a difference in system architecture? maybe because the book is for 386 and i'm running 686?

Answer (score 1):

0x2C is a comma `,` and 0x33 is the character `3`, and they appear at positions 2 and 3 in your string, as expected. (I'm a little confused as to what you were expecting, since you first say "should give me 37" and later say "rather than 0x3337".)

Answer (score 0):

You have defined a string constant when I suspect that you didn't mean to.  The following:

```
dw "13,37,99,99"
```

Will produce the following output:

```
Offset    00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B
          31 33 2C 33 37 2C 39 39 2C 39 39 00
```

Why?  Because:

- 31 is the ASCII code for '1'
- 33 is the ASCII code for '3'
- 2C is the ASCII code for ','
- ...
- 39 is the ASCII code for '9'
- NASM also null-terminates your string by putting 0 byte at the end (If you don't want your strings to be null-terminated use single quotes instead, `'13,37,99,99'`)

Take into account that `ax` holds two bytes and it should be fairly clear why `ax` contains `0x2C33`.

I suspect what you wanted was more along the lines of this (no quotes **and** we use `db` to indicate we are declaring byte-sized data instead of `dw` that declares word-sized data):

```
db 13,37,99,99
```

This would still give you `0x6363` (`ax` holds two bytes / conversion of 99, 99 to hex).  Not sure where you got `0x3337` from.

I recommend that you install yourself a [hex editor](http://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/) and have an experiment inspecting the output from NASM.